# How to press special characters without depending on keyboard layout with Java Robot?

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a small application that scans barcodes and translates their content into keystrokes.

Sending basic letters is pretty simple using the java.awt.Robot, but it gets complicated as soon as meta keys need to be involved in order to produce the characters.
KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH for example exists and maps to the right key on my keyboard, but sending a press and a release for that key will not result in a backslash because it is missing the ALT GR meta key (german layout) I could now go ahead and also send press and release for the VK_ALT_GRAPH key code, but this will stop working as soon as a different keyboard layout is used, that requires a different meta key like the american layout.

Is there any way to detect which keys must be pressed in order to produce a certain character or is there an API that accepts a Character or String and emits the corresponding key events? I'm open for any library that might implement this or could be extended to do so.

If there is no API or library available to become properly keyboard layout agnostic, is there an API or library that allows me to detect the currently configured keyboard layout? This would at least allow me to adjust keys if necessary.

The code I currently use for mapping characters to keystrokes can be found here:

```
fun mapActionToPrefixSuffix(action: Action): Pair<List<Pair<Int, Action.Do>>, List<Pair<Int, Action.Do>>> {

    val fKeys = (1..24).map { i -> "F$i" }.toSet()
    val special = mapOf(
            Pair("ENTER",     VK_ENTER),
            Pair("RETURN",    VK_ENTER),
            Pair("BACKSPACE", VK_BACK_SPACE),
            Pair("SPACE",     VK_SPACE),
            Pair("CTRL",      VK_CONTROL),
            Pair("SHIFT",     VK_SHIFT),
            Pair("ALT",       VK_ALT),
            Pair("ALTGR",     VK_ALT_GRAPH),
            Pair("CONTEXT",   VK_CONTEXT_MENU),
            Pair("WIN",       VK_META),
            Pair("TAB",       VK_TAB)
    )
    val charKeys = mapOf(
            Pair('\\', VK_BACK_SLASH),
            Pair('/',  VK_SLASH),
            Pair('!',  VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK),
            Pair(' ',  VK_SPACE),
            Pair(':',  VK_COLON),
            Pair(';',  VK_SEMICOLON),
            Pair('-',  VK_COMMA),
            Pair('@',  VK_AT),
            Pair('^',  VK_CIRCUMFLEX),
            Pair('=',  VK_EQUALS),
            Pair('_',  VK_UNDERSCORE),
            Pair('.',  VK_PERIOD),
            Pair('€',  VK_EURO_SIGN),
            Pair('$',  VK_DOLLAR),
            Pair('&',  VK_AMPERSAND),
            Pair('>',  VK_GREATER),
            Pair('<',  VK_LESS),
            Pair('(',  VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS),
            Pair('(',  VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS),
            Pair('[',  VK_OPEN_BRACKET),
            Pair(']',  VK_CLOSE_BRACKET),
            Pair('{',  VK_BRACELEFT),
            Pair('}',  VK_BRACERIGHT),
            Pair('\t', VK_TAB),
            Pair('\n', VK_ENTER),
            Pair('\r', VK_ENTER)
    )

    return if (action.key.length == 1) {
        val c = action.key[0]
        when {
            isLetterOrDigit(c) -> parseLetter(c)
            charKeys.containsKey(c) -> pressAndRelease(charKeys.getValue(c))
            else -> Pair(emptyList(), emptyList())
        }
    } else {
        val key = action.key.toUpperCase()
        when {
            fKeys.contains(key) -> parseFKey(key)
            special.containsKey(key) -> pressAndRelease(special.getValue(key))
            else -> Pair(emptyList(), emptyList())
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/pschichtel/VirtualScanner/blob/bfbe44bea8412713104d3051b6f7332aa8ee13c7/src/main/kotlin/tel/schich/virtualscanner/actions.kt#L61-L121

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Post the code here, don't link to your code. Links can break.

Comment: @VinceEmigh true. Copied it in, but I don't think it's super relevant to the question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to find a platform independent solution to the problem and went the manual route: Create a simple file that maps characters to a sequence of keyboard actions (pressing and releasing buttons). This way every user must create such a file for is keyboard layout in order to use the tool.